# Удаление/апдейт определенного объекта в коллекции

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Есть коллеция, в ней идут обьекты `{"name": имя, "score": число}`. Их 10 шт. При  добавлении новой записи надо чтобы либо удалялся обьект с наибольшим числом score, либо апдейтился. Как правильно находить этот обьект?

Comment: Так все-таки надо чтобы удалялся или апдейтился?

Comment: лучше и правильнее на сколько я понимаю апдейтить нужный обькт дабы не делать лишние движения. Но готов расмотреть и другие варианты)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала находим элемент с максимальным значением (вот пару способов)

```
   1. db.collection.find().sort({score:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
   2. db.collection.findOne({$query:{},$orderby:{score:-1}})
```

Ну а потом апдейтим то что нашли...